# Deployed App does not work with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, gwt, jdbc

the following Java Code does work fine with my Local Database, but when i try to use the Google Database i get following Error (also when its deployed):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
```

I already wrote the Connector into the Appennine-web.xml:

```
<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

My Java Code looks like the following (first class, where i get the connection):

```
package edu.example.server.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;




public class DbConnection {



private static Connection con = null;



private static String googleUrl = "jdbc:google:mysql://xx:xx/xx?user=root&password=xx";
//private static String localUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xx?user=root&password=xx";


  public static Connection connection() {

    if (con == null) {
        String url = null;
        try {


                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");



            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return con;
}

}
```

And the second class (where i try to get something):

```
package edu.example.server.db;

import java.sql.*;




public class BauteilMapper {


private static BauteilMapper bauteilMapper = null;


protected BauteilMapper() {
}


public static BauteilMapper bauteilMapper() {
if (bauteilMapper == null) 
  bauteilMapper = new BauteilMapper();


return bauteilMapper;
 }


public String findByKey(int id) {

Connection con = DbConnection.connection();

try {


Statement stmt = con.createStatement();



ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT idbauteil, name FROM bauteil "
+ "WHERE idbauteil=" + id);


if (rs.next()) {



String name = (rs.getNString("name"));


return name;
}

}
catch (SQLException e2) {
e2.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
return null;
}


}
```

I just can't find any mistake with the error report mentioned at the top.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Chris. I would look into this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Connect_to_your_database to make sure you followed all the steps. Seems like you did it, but I'm not sure where your <user-google-connector> is, so it's hard to say